# Como Recuperar nome do Usuário no Botframework?

Tags: c#, chatbot, bot-framework

Qual o código em C# para recuperar o nome do usuário durante a conversa?
[image: Chat]

Answer (score 2):

A documentação não ajuda muito mas acho que você está procurando a propriedade [`IDialogContext.Activity.From.Name`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.channelaccount.name?view=botbuilder-dotnet-3.0#Microsoft_Bot_Connector_ChannelAccount_Name).

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    string Nome_do_Usuario = context.Activity.From.Name;

}
```

Comment: Deu certo, Muito Obrigado Augusto Vasques!

Comment: Opa @MateusRodrigues. Se resolveu o seu problema você poderia por gentileza aceitar a resposta do Augusto como correta?